# Grails 3.1.1 Rest-API and Neo4J 2.3 basic example not working

Tags: rest, grails, neo4j, grails-orm

I'm trying to create a Grails 3.1.1 project with Neo4J as my database through the Gorm 5 support for Neo4J. I've created a new Grails project using the rest-api profile. I've added a domain class and a restful controller for this domain class.

```
class User {

    String firstName;

    static constraints = {
    }
}

class UserController extends RestfulController {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']
    UserController() {
        super(User)
    }
}
```

Then in the `init/BootStrap.groovy` file I've added some test data logging out the ids after saving.

```
def init = { servletContext ->
    User user1 = new User(firstName: "The Stand").save(flush:true);
    User user2 = new User(firstName: "The Shining").save(flush:true);
    log.info(user1.id);
    log.info(user2.id);
}
```

Before trying to use Neo4J as my db this all works fine. Hitting the index URL displays the users:

```
[{"id":1,"firstName":"The Stand"},{"id":2,"firstName":"The Shining"}]
```

Now I follow the instructions in http://grails.github.io/grails-data-mapping/latest/neo4j/manual/guide/gettingStarted.html#usingNeo4jStandalone

I add the Neo4J dependencies to my build.gradle as per instruction 2.1 and 2.4. I've assumed I need to do 2.4 as grails 3.1 runs with spring boot.

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:neo4j:5.0.0.RC1"
compile "org.grails:gorm-neo4j-spring-boot:5.0.0.RC1"
```

I remove the hibernate plugin in the same file:

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
```

I've not added any configuration for datasource so this should be using a basic embedded neo4j instance as per instructions.

For instruction 2.4 I add @ComponentScan although my file has `GrailsApp.run` and the instructions has `SpringApplication.run` so this is inconsistent. Finally I added @Entity to User domain class as per instruction 2.4.

Now when I restart application I'm told the `BootStrap` records have been saved with ids:

```
INFO grails.app.init.BootStrap - -8879732183286874112
INFO grails.app.init.BootStrap - -8879732183286833152
```

But now when I hit the URL to get all instances I get:

```
[]
```

rather than the expected:

```
[{"id":-8879732183286874112,"firstName":"The Stand"},{"id":-8879732183286833152,"firstName":"The Shining"}]
```

I've tried hitting the show endpoint using these ids but nothing. I've removed the configuration suggested in 2.4 but still nothing. I've tried adding records via the rest endpoints but I get other problems and exceptions none of which are very useful. I'm thinking that until these basic steps aren't working then it's not surprising that other attempts aren't working.

It appears from the log output that records have been added but it seems like I just can't get the app to retrieve them.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I just got the problem.

Try to add this in your domain classes :

```
static mapping = {
    id generator:'native'
}
```